# Accumulate something to something?

Tags: expressions

Here is the situation;

> There has been a value A, and now I'm replacing the value A with the new result of adding A and the new value B (i.e., A + B).

The simplest way that I can think of to describe this is "I'm accumulating B to A", but I can hardly find any of this usage on the internet. Could anyone recommend an idiomatic expression to describe this?

Comment: I'm incrementing A by B.

Answer (score 1):

You're perhaps overthinking this. You can simply say:

> I'm adding B to A

To me this implies what you're trying to say above.

As trivia, this operation in programming is often known as *addition assignment*, and would be written `A += B`